# JWT decryption and verify signature

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, jwt

I am trying to decrypt JWT token and verify signature using python. Though I found PyJWT, it does not actually encrypt/decrypt the payload, so I cannot use it. I also looked at https://github.com/IdentityPython/pyjwkest/tree/master/src/jwkest but the decrypt() method is actually returning plain text and then not sure how to "verify" on the plain text.
Can someone share example for decrypt a JWT token using private key and verify the signature using public key. Algo for decrypt: RSA-OAEP-256 and enc: A256GCM. Algo for signing was PS512